# Rails flat params to hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, parameters, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have this POST **param** (from the Google cart script) in Rails 3.

```
{
"shopping-cart.items.item-1.item-name"=>"Item one",
"shopping-cart.items.item-1.item-description"=>"An item",
"shopping-cart.items.item-1.unit-price"=>"10",
"shopping-cart.items.item-1.unit-price.currency"=>"GBP",
"shopping-cart.items.item-1.quantity"=>"1",

"shopping-cart.items.item-2.item-name"=>"Item two",
"shopping-cart.items.item-2.item-description"=>"Another item",
"shopping-cart.items.item-2.unit-price"=>"12.5",
"shopping-cart.items.item-2.unit-price.currency"=>"GBP",
"shopping-cart.items.item-2.quantity"=>"3",

"shopping-cart.items.item-3.item-name"=>"Item three",
"shopping-cart.items.item-3.item-description"=>"Yet another item",
"shopping-cart.items.item-3.unit-price"=>"20",
"shopping-cart.items.item-3.unit-price.currency"=>"GBP",
"shopping-cart.items.item-3.quantity"=>"2",

"edit_url"=>"http://somerailsapp/store/buy",
"_charset_"=>"UTF-8",
"controller"=>"order",
"action"=>"process"
}
```

What is the most effective way of converting this to the obvious hash?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to transform "dot-notation" string keys in a Hash into a nested Hash?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4364891/how-to-transform-dot-notation-string-keys-in-a-hash-into-a-nested-hash)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
params.map { |k,v| [k.split('.').reverse,v] }.map { |keys,val| keys.inject(val) { |val, e| { e => val }} }.inject({}) { |hsh, h| hsh.deep_merge(h) }
```

It may not be the most optimal way, but - unless we're talking about millions of items in the cart - it still does the job faster than a single DB query.

For your sample params the result should be:

```
{"shopping-cart"=>{"items"=>{"item-1"=>{"item-name"=>"Item one", "item-description"=>"An item", "unit-price"=>{"currency"=>"GBP"}, "quantity"=>"1"}, "item-2"=>{"item-name"=>"Item two", "item-description"=>"Another item", "unit-price"=>{"currency"=>"GBP"}, "quantity"=>"3"}, "item-3"=>{"item-name"=>"Item three", "item-description"=>"Yet another item", "unit-price"=>{"currency"=>"GBP"}, "quantity"=>"2"}}}, "edit_url"=>"http://somerailsapp/store/buy", "_charset_"=>"UTF-8", "controller"=>"order", "action"=>"process"}
```

You may also use

```
k.split('.').reverse.map { |k| sanitize_key(k) }
```

where `sanitize_key` gets rid of `item-` prefix and/or changes the item number to integer.

Edit: I just noticed that the price goes missing - so you may want to add `'.amount'` to the
keys ending with `unit-price`. Somehow this cart hash is not sanely structured...

Enjoy!

Comment: I agree, the cart hash is not helpful!

Comment: I believe your answer would work with something along the lines of executed first ...

cart = cart.each { |key,value| key.gsub!(/unit-price/,"unit-price.amount")}

.. does that seem along the right trail of thought?

One issue would be that the regex would also replace **...unit-price.currency** with **...unit-price.amount.currency**

I'm not best skilled in regex yet, is there a way to match a whole, literal string, or match unit-price AND NOT unit-price.currency?

Answer (score 1):

The ideal way is to change your parameters to reflect the structure you want.  For parameters that should be nested in a hash, such as `shopping-cart.items.item-1.item-name`, change the name of the parameter to `shopping-cart[items][item-1][item-name]`. Then rails will do the work for you.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have control over the parameter names. They have to be converted to a hash in the application.

Comment: Then you'll want to see Tass's comment about duplication.